# Adding an element into a HashSet inside a HashMap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this problem which I looked for into the net and I could be helped... I also looked other Questions and they didnt work i dont know why... So I need your help....

So this is a field in which I create the HashMap:

```
private HashMap <String,HashSet<String>> userBuisness = new HashMap <String,HashSet<String>>();
```

And this is my try to add an element (i take a line from a file, i split it and then i add these elements into my HashMap):

```
String output = inputReader.nextLine();
String fields[] = output.split("\t");
userBuisness.put(fields[0],fields[1]);
```

Comment: `fields[1]` is a `String`, not a `HashSet<String>`. You can build the latter using `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fields[1]))`.

Comment: Andy told you how to insert such an entry into the map. But ... why do you need a `HashSet<String>` type for your map values? Your code snippet shows that you are only putting a `String` typed value.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thats what my project asks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AndyTurner said in a comment:

> `fields[1]` is a `String`, not a `HashSet<String>`. You can build the latter using `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fields[1]))`.

But there are other issues with this snippet too. It would be better to rewrite like this, pay close attention to every little detail that I changed:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> userBusiness = new HashMap<>();

...

String[] fields = output.split("\t");
userBusiness.put(fields[0], new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(fields[1])));
```

Comment: You know, I'd bet that code is in a loop, and if input is `A B`, `A C`, the result should be `{A=[B, C]}`, not the `{A=[C]}` this code gives. Otherwise, why make it a Map-Set, right?

Comment: yes it is in a while loop. Until the file has next Line